# Run a Macro at a specific time for a certain time amount and stop that macro or line of code to run another macro or line for a new time?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

[image]I have a worksheet that on Mac it has a add button that will increase the value of the Cabs Loaded each time you press it. I have multiple time locations 0530, 0600, 0630, etc. That the one adds button needs to increase based on the current time listed.

The code below is what I have tried, it runs the function code first once it reaches the time cap. The sub code runs along with the code for the function once it reached said time. I need it to stop the first addition at H10 so it will only add on the next at H12 for a certain timed amount before going to the next ones.

```
    Sub Button_One()
    If Time <= TimeSerial(18, 26, 0) Then GoTo Next1
    If Time >= TimeSerial(18, 28, 0) Then Exit Sub
    Sheets("A-1 Am").Range("h12").Value = Sheets("A-1 Am").Range("h12").Value + 1
Next1: Button_One1 
End Sub
    
    Function Button_One1()
    Sheets("A-1 Am").Range("h10").Value = Sheets("A-1 Am").Range("h10").Value + 1
    End Function
    
    If Time < TimeSerial(13, 15, 0) Then
    
        RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, cRunIntervalSeconds)
        Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
            Schedule:=True
    End If
```

Any information to get this to work will be appreciated!!! I've been trying for weeks to figure it out!

Comment: This is only for a mac os then?

Comment: Sorry about that I corrected the information on the post, I hope it helps. If not let me know I'm still learning.